# IE drag and drop on input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

what am trying to do is make IE behave like the default behafiour FF and chrome have when you drag a file on a input element of type file issue is im not exactly sure what attribute am suppose to be appending a value to furthermore i think my event dosnt event trigger here is a little code i was using

```
addEvent($('#drop'),'dragover',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false; //a IE thing
        });

        addEvent($('#drop'),'drop',function(e){
            $('#details').innerHTML=e.dataTransfer.files;
        })
```

so as a clear question can anyone post the code or a link to add the drop event to the input type file and handle it as if i clicked browse and manually added a file. thanks in advance

Comment: _return false; //a IE thing_?

Comment: which version of IE is this supposed to work in?

Comment: @putvande i read somewhere that IE needed it. figured it dosnt hurt so why not. tho i can confirm IE 11 still prevents the default without it

Comment: Why are you having `return false` and `ev.preventDefault()` both? ...

Comment: @alex_zander, no IE doesn't actually need it..that is to prevent the code execution..the code execution stops here and no further execution takes place...

Comment: @dandavis i figure IE 10+ is good

Comment: maybe e.target.files=e.dataTransfer.files; e.target.onchange.call(e.target); but i don't think you can set .files, so you might have to slightly abstract, depending on how your input change event is coded. we can't see that, so you're on your own...

Comment: @dandavis coded as default as i havent scripted any action to the onchange event. so i guess that code would be the default thing that happends when you click "browse" to select a file

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to append to the file input using the information i got from the file api